# Replace string in big sql file (15 go) bash

Tags: mysql, bash, docker, shell, in-place

I have to replace this string in dump file :

```
use clients_db;
```

by

```
use client;
```

The name of database is different between the environment src and dest.

I tried with using sed, but it doesn't work because the file is so big.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: If you don't have enough free drive space for it to work with sed, I'm betting it won't work with anything without some major hurdles.

Comment: What do you do when the change is made? Do you import the data into the database? If yes, show the command to import the file.

Comment: not enough space. Yes, I try to import de data into the database

Comment: the command is : docker exec -i database mysql -uuser -ppass clients < clients_db_dump.sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job without editing your file:

```
sed 's/^use clients_db;/use client;/' clients_db_dump.sql | docker exec -i database mysql -uuser -ppass clients
```

I assume that there are no spaces before `use clients_db;`.

Comment: It works !! Thank's ! When we do this, sed doesn't create a tmp file ?

Comment: `sed` creates in this case no temporary file.